# silverlight asking to install when it's already installed

Tags: silverlight, browser

Does anyone else have difficulty with this problem? SL is already installed on each of my browsers but, sometimes (not all the time), the browser shows the SL logo asking to install it. Is there a reason this happens even though the website works perfectly at times? When I re-load the page the logo usually goes away and solves the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Often this is a version issue, in that if the silverlight app was compiled against a newer version than what is on your machine, you will get that SL logo. However that doesn't explain why a reload of the page solves your problem.

Comment: I've tried to reinstall with a newer version, but it still gives me the error sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AgControl.AgControl does not have READ access fix

1. Run regedit (start->run->regedit)
2. Navigate to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AgControl.AgControl (if you get a message that says "AgControl.AgControl cannot be opened. An error is preventing this key from being opened. Details: Access is denied." proceed to the "Taking ownership of the key" section)
3. Right click and choose "Permissions"
4. Click "Add"
5. Either add your windows username or your network username in the the "Enter the object names to select" and click "Check Names". Your name should take the proper format. If it does not try clicking "Advanced" and searching for your username. My windows username was the one I used.
6. Click OK
7. Select your new username in the top pane and in the lower pane (Permissions for ) check the Allow box next to Read.
8. Click OK

Check Silverlight installation in IE by going to http://www.silverlight.net/

Taking ownership of the key (If you're getting access denied errors while trying to set permissions)

You can download the following tool from microsoft to open an
instance of regedit as system:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553

The following command line will open a "system" regedit:

psexec -s -i regedit

(Note: You have to execute this command line from an "administrator" command
prompt [right-click command prompt and click run as administrator])

Return to step 3 above